# Netlify Nitro Deploys

Tags: deployment, build, netlify

What are Netlify nitro deploys? I am now seeing this in my deploy logs, but there is nothing in their documentation explaining what this is doing:

`11:37:18 AM: [feature enabled]: Nitro deploys enabled. Buckle up! ⚡️`

Comment: Same here. Out of curiosity, Are you seeing this while manually ZIP deploying via API? Because I am and my deploy logs don't do anything other than post that message

Comment: Most of the time our builds are kicked off from a Contentful webhook. I think Netlify was recently experiencing an outage around the time this feature was implemented and that is likely why your builds weren't running properly. Hopefully they're working for you now. @zelusp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Official answer from Netlify community](https://community.netlify.com/t/feature-enabled-nitro-deploys-enabled-buckle-up/9848/3?u=talves)

Nitro deploys enabled. Buckle up! ⚡️

> This indicates the build used a new optimization for how files are uploaded when a deploy is finished.
>
> This feature is enabled for all Netlify sites at this time. It is a new feature and this log entry is there to help us know when it is in use.